# Spyder Python 3.6 windowed size

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, spyder

see the screenshot for the problem. In window mode I can not click on any icons, I have to aim much lower to actually click it. In fullscreen I have no problems but I can not click on any tabls like File, Edit, Search, Source, etc.

[image]

Does anyone know a workaround to fix this problem?

> Python 3.6  - Spyder 3.3.1 - Spyder-Kernels 0.2.6 - Windows 10 64Bit

I tried to uninstall spyder and update anaconda with `conda update -all` and `conda install spyder` but the problem still remains.

Comment: on windows, mac or linux?

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention that, I am using Windows 10 64Bit

Comment: Please close the Help pane.That should fix this.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba Thank yo so much, may I ask you to write this as an answer so I can mark it as answered?

Comment: @mafin, done. Glad to be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) This problem is caused by our Help pane, but unfortunately we don't understand yet how to fix it. A temporary solution is to close that pane to avoid this behavior.